# kustomize patch overwriting parameter name and values

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I'm using kustomize and attempting to patch some helm parameters into the grafana configuration I have the below configuration file grafana.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: prod-k8s-grafana
  labels:
    environment: prod
    project: k8s
    role: grafana
spec:
  project: prod-k8s
  source:
    repoURL: 'https://github.com/helm/charts.git'
    path: 'stable/grafana'
    targetRevision: 'ba1d08a129255167457480e29339ab5bfe75d918'
    helm:
      parameters:
      - name: service.type
        value: LoadBalancer
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
  destination:
    namespace: prod-k8s-grafana
```

Then I have my kustomization file which I'm using to add patched values- specifically to the helm parameters section. When I add a patch like below, it patches the values, but it remove the original name value defined in the grafana.yaml file:

```
patches:
- target:
    kind: Application
  patch: |-
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: Application
    metadata:
      name: xxx
    spec:
      destination:
        server: https://DSKJHDAKJSH4HDSKHDKSJ0E56C7420CCF041E9.sk1.eu-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
- target:
    kind: Application
    name: prod-k8s-grafana
  patch: |-
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: Application
    metadata:
      name: prod-k8s-grafana
    spec:
      source:
        helm:
          parameters:
          - name: 'datasources."datasources\.yaml".datasources[0].url'
            value: 'http://prod-k8s-prometheus-cluster02-server.prod-k8s-prometheus.svc.cluster.local'
          - name: persistence.storageClassName
            value: gp2
          - name: 'datasources."datasources\.yaml".apiVersion'
            value: '1'
          - name: 'datasources."datasources\.yaml".datasources[0].name'
            value: Prometheus
```

So that when I check run `kustomize build` command, the the output it removes:

```
      - name: service.type
        value: LoadBalancer
```

It therefore appears that patching these name and values overwrites the parameters from grafana.yaml.

How can I ensure the patch appends the patched name a vales, rather than overwriting?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue recently, don't know if this is the perfect solution but if you use `patchesJson6902` and add env variables at the position 0 it won't delete the other one :

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0
  value:
    name: ONE
    value: '1'
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0
  value:
    name: TWO
    value: '2'
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0
  value:
    name: THREE
    value: '3'
```